# SQL table merge with special rules

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have two tables

```
CREATE TABLE df1 (
    src varchar(255),
    dst varchar(255)
);

insert into df1 (src, dst) 
values 
('src1', 'dst1'), 
('src2', 'dst2'),
('src3', 'dst3');

CREATE TABLE df2 (
    src varchar(255),
    dst varchar(255)
);

insert into df2 (src, dst) 
values 
('dst1', 'dstDst1'), 
('dst1', 'dstDst2'),
('dst3', 'dstDst3');
```

I want to merge them in this way (pseudo code):

```
if df1.dst = df2.src:
  df1.dst = list(df1.dst, df2.dst)
else:
  no op
```

using the example above, the merged table becomes

```
CREATE TABLE df3 (
    src varchar(255),
    dst varchar(255)
);

insert into df3 (src, dst) 
values 
('src1', 'dst1, dstDst1, dstDst2'), 
('src2', 'dst2'),
('src3', 'dst3, dstDst3');
```

How do I build table df3 from df1 and df2? NOTE the final table dst column can be a list or string concat, either way is fine.

Comment: What's your dbms?

Comment: @D-Shih snowflake

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to use `OUTER JOIN` with below functions.

MySql you can try to use  `GROUP_CONCAT` function

```
SELECT d1.src,coalesce(CONCAT(d1.dst,',',GROUP_CONCAT(d2.dst SEPARATOR ',')),d1.dst) dst
FROM df1 d1
LEFT JOIN df2 d2
ON d1.dst = d2.src
GROUP BY d1.src,d1.dst
```

[sqlfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=4be775c1b39e39496562595bb5e2cbbb)

Postgresql you can try to use `string_agg` function

```
SELECT src,
       CASE WHEN concat_result IS NULL 
        THEN  dst
        ELSE CONCAT(dst,',',concat_result)
       END dst
FROM (
    SELECT d1.src, d1.dst ,string_agg(d2.dst , ',') concat_result
    FROM df1 d1
    LEFT JOIN df2 d2
    ON d1.dst = d2.src
    GROUP BY d1.src,d1.dst
) t1
```

[sqlfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=7c1eda5b812267ff2d6c3edd1a75ff93)

**EDIT**

If you are using snowflake you can try to use [listagg](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/listagg.html) in subquery, because your expected result needs to be judgment `concat_result` whether null, so we can use `CASE WHEN` expression to do it.

```
SELECT src,
       CASE WHEN concat_result IS NULL 
        THEN dst
        ELSE CONCAT(dst,',',concat_result)
       END dst
FROM (
    SELECT d1.src, d1.dst ,listagg(d2.dst, ',') within group (ORDER BY d2.dst) concat_result
    FROM df1 d1
    LEFT JOIN df2 d2
    ON d1.dst = d2.src
    GROUP BY d1.src,d1.dst
) t1
```

Comment: Actually, the coalesce is not needed here since d1.dst will always be non NULL. So the current query actually will generate `dst2,` with the comma. Could you update the solution such that it will take care of the trailing comma? Thanks a lot in advance. This solutions is great!

Comment: @drdot I had edited my answer you can try it